# Pattern and Matches: Formatting a text file

Tags: java, regex, io

I'm attempting to take an input file that looks like so:

SomeElement1|SomeElementWithDifferentLength2|SomeElement3|AnElementI'llIgnore4|Something5|
Element1|DifferentLength2|Element3|AnElementI'llIgnore4|Element5|

And format it into columns with specific spacing. I'm very new to java and come from a C++ background. Anyways I was looking into establishing a pattern with regex and then looking for matches. I'm not sure what the syntax in regex to indentify a specific character (a pipe "|") so I can determine the pattern.

Does this seem like a good approach, and if so what would the syntax for Pattern.compile("Regex syntax") be and how would I determine matches with it?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what the output should look like?

Comment: The first element will begin at position 46 (preceeded by 45 spaces), the second element will begin at position 120, the third at 160, The Fourth at 162, the Fifth is ignored, and then finally a "*" is placed at 177. The number of rows is not fixed, but the first thing my program will do is determine the number of lines so that integer can be called if need be.

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest thing would be:

1. Turn each line into an array with String.split("|")
2. Create an array of ints with the length of each column
3. Create a StringBuilder to hold the reformatted line
4. Loop through the array from line 1, padding each string to the length from the array in line 2, and then appending it to the StringBuilder.

If it's possible for fields to have an embedded pipe and thus you have to have some mechanism for escaping them, then instead of split() you'd have to write code to parse the columns yourself. I suppose you could write a Regex for that but I think that would be more work than just looping through characters looking for pipes.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use  [String.split()](http://www.java-examples.com/java-string-split-example) ? e.g.

```
String[] res = line.split("\\|");
```

(note that the `split()` method takes a regexp, so you have to escape the pipe).

You can then iterate through the resultant array and use [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to output with padding/formatting etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the String.split(String regex) Method.

Answer (score 0):

If you can read the file contents as a string then you can do any of the following:

- directly replace the "|" with a certain number of spaces: `stringContents.replaceAll("\\|", "  ")`
- split the string at "|": `stringContents.split("\\|");`

Remember, the "|" is a special character in regular expressions and is interpreted as an "OR" operation, which is why it needs to be escaped with a backwards slash (i.e. two backwards slashes)

Answer (score 0):

Do not reinvent the wheel. Use Apache [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) and check StringUtils.

I assume you want fixed length columns; the library provides leftPad() or rightPad() methods plus a heap of other String manipulations.

In short:

1. split using `String.split()`
2. loop over the array and reformat using `StringUtils`